# Como criar método POST, PUT e DELETE em aplicação Grails?

Tags: restful, groovy, grails

Tenho uma aplicação Grails 2.4.2 que desejo comunicar com uma outra aplicação, e essa interação deverá ocorrer através de um serviço Rest fornecido pelo Grails.
Hoje da forma como está implementado basta eu informar .json no final da URL que ele me retorna os dados formatados. Contudo gostaria de saber como faço para manipular essas implementações a fim de adicionar os métodos `POST`, `PUT` e `DELETE`.

Fiz uma pesquisa na [documentação oficial](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.2/guide/theWebLayer.html#mappingToControllersAndActions), com isso cheguei a seguinte codificação:

***UrlMappings.groovy***

```
class UrlMappings {

static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    "/"(controller:"main")
    "500"(view:'/error')

    "/patrimonios"(resource:'Patrimonio')
    }
}
```

Quando rodo a aplicação e acesso o link `http://localhost:8080/Patrimonio/patrimonios` tenho uma página em branco como retorno.
Testei os métodos POST e DELETE através do addon POSTER e nada aconteceu também.
Sendo assim, gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de proceder para atingir o objetivo desejado?

***UrlMappings.groovy (EDITADO)***

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(controller:"main")
        "500"(view:'/error')

        "/api/patrimonio/"(controller: "PatrimonioController") {
            action = [GET: "get"]
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abaixo segue um exemplo que uso em uma aplicação em Grails (2.2.5) que é um serviço REST consumido por outra aplicação, também desenvolvida Grails (2.5.0).

No URLMapping:

```
    "/api/client/$labcode/$cliCode"(controller: "client") {
        action = [GET: "get"]
    }

    "/api/client"(controller: "client") {
        action = [POST: "save", PUT:"update"]
    }
```

O 1o URLMapping especifica que qualquer requisição HTTP do tipo **GET** que chegar para **/api/client/$labcode/$cliCode** será redirecionada para a action "**get**" do controlador "**client**".

**$labcode** e **$cliCode** são parametros passados para a action.

Exemplo de requisição HTTP GET que é capturada pelo 1o URL Mapping:

https://localhost:8443/Service/api/client/BRMIN01/CL-000223

nesse contexto, a aplicação se chama Service. O restante está exatamente no padrão para captura do URL Mapping.

Já a segundo mapping, especifica que qualquer requisição HTTP do tipo POST para **/api/client** será redirecionada para a action "**save**" do controlador "**client**". Já requisições do tipo **PUT** são direcionadas para a action "**update**" do mesmo controlador.

No exemplo da pergunta, pode-se fazer isso:

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?" {
    [POST: "save", PUT:"update", DELETE:"delete"]
    constraints {
        // apply constraints here
    }
 }
```

Para esse caso, está se especificando que requisições HTTP do tipo POST,PUT e DELETE que obedeçam a regra do mapeamento, serão direcionadas para as actions save, update e delete, respectivamente.

Sobre as páginas em branco, foi identificado pelo *chat* que estava sendo passado um ID inexistente no banco de dados.

Comment: Fiz a modificação conforme sugerido (codificação no primeiro post), apenas adequando para o projeto aqui. Ao tentar acessar o link http://localhost:8080/Patrimonio/patrimonio/api/patrimonio tenho como retorno `HTTP Status 404 - /Patrimonio/patrimonio/api/patrimonio`

Comment: Vou atualizar a resposta te mostrando como é feito uma requisição HTTP GET no meu sistema.

Comment: Entendi, sendo assim se eu falar que o método `GET` deverá chamar a função `show` do meu controlador ao digitar a url acima eu devo ter acesso a todos os registros cadastrados certo?

Comment: Veja bem, nesse caso, creio que o show ao qual você se refere tem um GSP de mesmo nome, correto? Note que o sistema que estou demonstrando é Restful (ou pelo menos quase). Eu nao tenho GSPs nessa aplicação. A única coisa que ela faz é servir com XML ou JSON as aplicações que desejam consumí-la. Se sua aplicação tem os dois papéis, ou seja, uma aplicação normal com GSPs e outro papel como uma API Restful, então sugiro que você divida como mostrado acima. Tudo que vem depois de /api/ é Rest. Tudo que vem sem /api/ é uma aplicação normal, com GSPs, etc.

Comment: Eu tenho uma aplicação Grails que desejo comunicar com uma outra desenvolvida em Android. Hoje já consigo consumir a aplicação Android através da aplicação Grails. Para isso acesso o .json de cada controller da aplicação Grails. O que gostaria é acessar os métodos save, update e delete que estão no controller do Grails pelo Android. Desculpe se me expressei mau antes. Sendo assim é melhor eu criar um controller separado só para as funções rest?

Comment: Aqui, criei uma sala no chat, melhor discutir isso lá.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27112/discussion-between-cantoni-and-thiago).